# PostgreSQL - How to check if I am in SSL Tunnel

Tags: postgresql, ssl, jdbc

Everything is in title.

Do you know a simple way (as SQL request) to check if a request send to Postgres is in SSL Tunnel? I use JDBC.
My application support SSL. I need it in order to realise a test. I didn't find something interesting but I could miss some information!

Thank you very much!

Comment: If the tunnel is working properly there is no way you can detect it, and no earthy reason I can think of why you would need to know.

Comment: @EJP As part of an integration-test it is a good check to test in example if the specification forces us to connect via SSL.

Comment: Thank you mates for your answers!

I realised some test when I change variable's sytem :
- ssl mode set to allowed/required/disabled for both client and server mode to test my database connection.

I'd like to realise another one to check if request are really secured. But it possible that's not handle by postgres sql!

Comment: postgres ssl or tunnel ssl?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-info.html  doesn't seem to have anything for indicating which protocol is being used.

Comment: Yeah, I believe that there is no way to realise what I want simple. Thank anyway mates!